# Is there an initial mouse cursor size defined in Xorg

Tags: cursor, xorg

Is there an initial mouse cursor size defined in the Xorg source code, because when I use a 4k monitor, no matter how I change the resolution and scaling of the monitor, when I log out the user, the cursor size on the user login interface is the same.

But I only saw some cursor display functions and some cursor size transfers in the xorg code, but did not see the specific default value of the cursor size